# Does push command of git replace whole code

Tags: git

Earlier my code was in swift 3.0 now I migrated to swift 4.2. I resolved all the conflicts and compile-time errors now code is working fine. My question is I have lots of modified classes in the project and **if I do commit and push** (Without pull- If I do pull it will compare my local code and repo code) is it going to replace on repo with new code or it's going to merge my previous code and new code.

Comment: If no one has changed the code in your repository. Then it will overwrite. You can however revert back to your code at any time. If Your repository has contributors and someone already pushed their code. Then you will have to fetch it first and then push the merged code.

Comment: The repository is up to date. No one is contributed yet. Is it going to override for sure? @Silverfang

Comment: Whatever you have in your folder that contain `.git folder` will go to github repo as it is  excluding what you have mentioned in the `.gitignore`. Even if you mess up git can revert back to any commit that you have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question itself has some assumptions that just aren't true.  To understand what happens with `git push`, you need to know these things:

- The unit of storage that you use in Git is the *commit*.
- Each commit consists of two parts: a snapshot of *all* of your files (not a changeset), which is the main bulk of the commit, and some *metadata:* information about the commit, such as who made it, and when.
- Every commit has a unique name, which is its hash ID.  The hash IDs are big ugly strings of letters and digits, like `51ebf55b9309824346a6589c9f3b130c6f371b8f`.  This hash ID is the same in *every* Git repository everywhere, so that it's easy to tell if you have the commit, or not: your Git just checks *do I have `51ebf55b9309824346a6589c9f3b130c6f371b8f`* and if so, it has *that* commit (not some other commit).
- Every commit can store the hash ID(s) of one or more *previous* commits, in the metadata.  These are called the commit's *parent* or *parents*.  This lets Git string commits together backwards.
- Everything stored inside a commit—all the files *and* all the metadata—is completely, totally, 100% read-only.  Nothing about any commit can ever be changed!  The files inside a commit are stored in a special, compressed, read-only, Git-only form that only Git can actually read.
- Git is not really about files at all; Git is all about *commits*.  Commits do store files, but you either get all of them—a whole commit—or none of them because you don't have that commit.
- The usual goal of a `git push` is not to *replace* commits but rather to *add* commits.

When you worry about files, you're not worrying about Git itself.  You're worrying instead about making Git actually *useful*.  Frozen, Git-ified files that only Git can read are great for archival, but useless for doing any actual work.  Hence, Git gives you a work area into which the files get copied out *from* a commit, and expanded back into your computer's normal file form.  This work area is your *working tree* or *work-tree*.

The files that are in your work-tree are not the committed files!  They are just your *work-tree*.  You can do whatever you want to these.  A `git push` does not use these files and has no effect on these files.<sup>1</sup>  The `git push` command sends *commits*, not files (though, again, of course commits do *hold* files, in their snapshots).

Since each commit has a big ugly random-looking hash ID, any Git can easily tell whether it has some commit, or not.  When you run `git push origin`, your Git calls up another Git, at the URL it has stored under the name `origin`.  Your Git tells that Git: *Hey, I have the commit with hash `H`, do you have it?*  If they say *no* your Git will give them `H`, but first, your Git will say: *OK, `H`'s parent is this other hash `G`, do you have it?*  If they say *no* your Git will give them commit `G` too, and offer `G`'s parent hash, whatever that is.  This repeats until the two Gits get to a hash that the *receiving* Git *does* already have.

This is how your Git knows which commits to send: your Git offers, then sends, their Git the commits that you have, that they don't.  Commits that *they* have and *you* don't, don't matter here—push only *sends* **your** commits; it doesn't *receive* any from them.

Remember, all commits are strung together like links on chains.  If your latest commit has some big ugly hash `H`, and your latest commit's *parent* is commit `G`, your `H` *points to* your `G`:

```
          G <-H
```

But of course your `G` has some big ugly hash ID stored as *its* parent.  Let's call that commit `F`, so that `G` points to `F`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

`F` has some other parent, which also points back, and so on.  This keeps going all the way back to the *very first commit anyone ever made for this repository*.  That first commit *doesn't* point back to an earlier commit, because it can't: there isn't anything earlier.

The thing about these hash IDs, though, is that they *look* random, and mere humans are never going to be able to type them in or remember them.  How will we every remember that `H` is the *last* commit for your branch named `matster`?

That's not really a big problem though: we have a *computer*.  The *computer* can remember that for us.  Let's just have it store somewhere, maybe in a file, the fact that the *last* commit for `master` is hash `H` (whatever the big ugly hash ID really is).  Then the *name* `master` *points to* `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

(where all the lines connecting commits are really just backwards-pointing arrows, coming out of each commit and pointing leftward in these drawings, where I've put earlier commits to the left and later ones to the right).

So, if your Git has `H` as its *latest*, your `git push` to `origin` will call up the other Git at `origin` and offer commit `H`.  If they want it, your Git will offer `H`'s parent `G` too.  If they want that, your Git will offer `G`'s parent, and so on—and at some point they'll say *I already have that one*, which means they have it *and every earlier commit too*.  (Remember, hash IDs are the same in *every* Git.  So if they have `F`, and `F` points back to `E`, they must have gotten `E` earlier too.  If `E` points back to `D`, they must have `D`, and so on.)  So all they need to be complete here is `G` and `H`.

Your Git will now package up both `G` and `H` and send them.  Their Git will put those commits in a temporary holding area.  Now your Git does its last step of `git push`, which is to ask them: *Please, if it's OK, set **your** `master` to point to commit `H`.*  That is, **they have their own name `master`**.  Presumably, their `master` points to `F`, not `H`.

If this is the case, when you give them `G` (which points back to `F`) and `H` (which points back to `G`), they now have this:

```
       G--H
      /
...--F   <-- master
```

Note how it's possible to "insert" the `-G-H` commits *without losing anything*, because `H` points to `G` which points to `F`.  They'll go ahead and take `G` and `H` for real, and make *their* `master` point to `H` too:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

just like in your Git.

---

<sup>1</sup>The Git repository that *receives* a `git push` can, if it wants to, extract one of the new commits that were just pushed.  If it extracts that commit to a work-tree, obviously that will affect that work-tree.  But that's up to the *receiving* Git: does it extract at all?  If so, where does it extract?  That's not your problem: you're just *sending* commits.

---

## Summary

Nothing happens to any *files*.  You offer them *commits*.  They ask for the ones that are new to them, and say *no thanks, I already have that one* to the ones that they already have.  Then your Git asks, politely, if they can please *add* those commits to their collection.

If the commits do in fact *add*, they will probably accept this polite request (especially if you got this far at all—if their Git doesn't like your Git, you probably never got a chance to offer any commits in the first place).  Where things go wrong here is if they have, in some way, added a commit that you *don't* have.  If for instance they have:

```
...--F--I   <-- master
```

and you give them `G` and `H` so that they now have:

```
       G--H
      /
...--F--I   <-- master
```

and you ask them to make their `master` point to commit `I`, they'd end up with:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
      \
       I
```

which would *lose* their commit `I`.  Git *finds* commits by starting at branch names (and tag names and other such names, but let's not worry about this here) and working *backwards*.  From `H`, we go to `G`, then to `F` and on backwards.  We never visit commit `I` at all in this process.  So if they made *their* `master` remember commit `H`, they would lose commit `I`.

Your `git push` succeeds when it only *adds* commits to *their* repository.  It fails—and hence requires some other action—if it will *throw away* some commit(s) in their repository.

#### If and when this kind of `git push` *does* fail, you will often *get* commits

Suppose they have commit `I`.  (Where did it come from?  It must have come from some *other* Git, not yours.  If you're the only person who ever works on this repository, they *can't* have commit `I`!)

You might now run `git fetch origin` to *get* `I` *from* them.  Then you will have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
      \
       I   <-- origin/master
```

in *your* repository.  The name `origin/master` here—which is a *remote-tracking name*—is your Git's way of remembering that *their* Git's `master` points to commit `I`.  The `git fetch` operation *gets* any commits *they* have that you don't.  Just like `git push` gives them commits you have that they don't, `git fetch` gets commits that they have that you don't.  All of this works by those hash IDs!  So the hash IDs are crucial, even though puny humans can't really use them.  Git gives us *branch names* to help us remember the *last* hash ID for the branch, and *remote-tracking names* to help us remember some *other* Git's branch-names-and-hash-IDs.

This is what `git push` and `git fetch` are about: sending and receiving commits.  The *branch names* here are just used to *find* the commits.  Your Git has *your* branch names, and their Git has *their* branch names.

If you're in a complex situation where multiple users `git push` to one central repository location, sometimes you'll need to get *new* commits that someone else—some *third* Git—sent to the central Git.  You'll use `git fetch` to get them, but then you will need to *mix together* your commits and their commits.  This is where things really get complicated.  Some people use `git pull`, although I recommend newbies *not* start with `git pull`, because there are different ways to combine your work and their work.  The `pull` command means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command to combine work*.  You won't know yet which second command you want!  But that's something to worry about later.

Comment: Thanks for the better explanation the answer covers almost all concepts about git repo management.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Silverfang, if you are the only person working on a branch, it will simply update the remote branch with your local files. You only need to pull, if there have been made changes on the remote branch (Git will also not allow you to push to the remote branch if there are unmerged changes).

If you want to be totally sure everything is fine, do the following:

```
git stash // stash your changes on your local branch
git checkout -b <feature branch name> // create new feature branch
git stash pop // unstash your changes
git commit -a -m "Some description" // Commit your changes to create a checkpoint in git you can return to if things go bad
git checkout <dev branch> // Go back to dev branch...
git pull // ...get the latest state...
git checkout <feature branch name> // ... go back to the feature branch ...
git merge <dev branch> // ... and merge your changes in.
```

If things go totally bad and you want to return to your previous state, you can do so by

```
git restore *
```

Don't forget to commit your merge from dev, if you are happy with the result. :)

**Note:** If there are unmerged changes on the remote branch and you want to overwrite them, you can usually do so in your merge tool by selecting your version on a file. Though, you should have proper testing in place to not screw things up this way.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer before doing migration to new label just make sure that repo is up to date

1) **Commit the changes**

2) Instead of pull and push just **push the code** it will override the whole branch with the local changeset